# How to add Form Header?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am looping through my `forms` to change `backcolor` of `form header` via VBA code. However, my code breaks for the `forms` which do not have a `form header` inserted. I used the line below but it gives an `error` saying `section number is invalid` which looks true since my `form` does not have a `header` in the first place.

```
me.Form.Section(1).Visible = True
```

I know how to add `form header` manually but there are too many `forms` and it is tedious to change them one by one. Can someone help how to `add form hearder` via VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it dawned to me that I needed to fix the line of code as:

```
If me.Section(1).Visible = True then
 'Do color change

End if
```

It solved the issue. I did not need to add `form headers`.